# Why my Widget Style always change back to GTK+ Style automatically?

Tags: kde, widgets, style

Using KDE, when changing Widget Style using

> Setting -> Application Appearance -> Style -> Application -> Widget style

Every time I change the Widget style into Cleanlooks (or others), the style of every window that is currently open changes immediately. But when I open new windows, the style of the newly open window become GTK+ Style again.

Why?

Comment: You might have issues with write access to configuration files. Look in your home directory for files whose owner is not you.